# Como hacer una relación con Laravel desde la llave primaria a la foranea?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Lo que deseo realizar es hacer la siguiente relación osea a traves del usuario obtener los roles que tiene.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 public function permiso(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\permisos', 'user_id');
    }
```

intente con el codigo anterior pero no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Si bien entiendo, un usuario puede tener uno o mas roles.
Siendo asi, en el modelo de `users` deberias agregar lo siguiente

```
public function permisos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Permisos');
    }
```

Laravel, en este caso Eloquent determinará de forma automatica que columna es la que mas conviene para hacer esta relacion, buscando en este caso el nombre de la primera tabla mas el sufijo `_id` osea `user_id` en tu tabla de roles.

Entonces si quieres consultar los roles desde el controlador de usuario seria de esta forma:

```
$lospermisos = App\User::find(1)->permisos;
```

Donde `permisos` es el nombre de la función de la relación que se indico en el Modelo de Users.

Ahora bien en el caso de que sea una relacion uno a uno deberas ocupar `hasOne('App\Permisos')` donde se cumple la misma regla de buscar la relacion con la columna `user_id` en la tabla de roles.

En el caso de que tu clave foranea no tenga como sufijo `_id` tendras que especificarle como se llama la llave `return $this->hasMany('App\Permiso', 'foreign_key', 'tu_clave_foranea');`

Y por ultimo, ya que estabas utilizando `belongsTo` que sería una forma inversa de realizar la relacion tendrias que en el Modelo de Permisos hacer lo siguiente

```
public function permiso()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

Y en el controlador sería:

```
$permiso = App\Permiso::find(1);

echo $permiso->user->name;
```

Espero esto te pueda ayudar.
La documentacion de mi respuesta se basa en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)